# How can Newton's method ever work in neural netowrks?

Tags: taylor-expansion, newton-raphson, neural-networks

In neural networks, we try to find successively better weights for the network by trying to minimize some error function. Gradient descent can be used. The error function may not be convex with respect to the weights of the network.

Recently I came across the [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) for finding a root of a function used for minimizing the error function by means of approximating the function with quadratic function and minimizing that in each step.

Let $f$ be the error function to minimize. The Newton's method goes like this.
Approximate $f$ with second order Taylor polynomial.

$f(a_1+x) = f(a_1) + f'(a_1)(x-a_1)+\frac{f''(a_1)}{2}(x-a_1)^2$

According to the method, the update is as follows.

$x=-\frac{f'(a_1)}{f''(a_1)}$

and so

$a_2 = a_1 -\frac{f'(a_1)}{f''(a_1)}$

If $f$ is concave around $a$, then the update can be in the direction of local maximum instead of local minimum.

My question is, how can this method ever work, if we find ourselves in a concave part of the error function? Then the Newtons method will direct us to the local maximum, which is definitely undesirable.

How is this case handled in neural networks? Am I missing something?

Comment: I think Newton's method is not used to train neural networks. The linear system that must be solved at each iteration is too large to solve efficiently.

Comment: The method meant here is the method for finding root of a function numerically. In this case, it is looking for the root of a derivative. It needs the hessian of the function, but in practice, some approximations of the hessian are used.

Comment: Newton's method is not a minimization method but a root finder. You can use it to find the roots of the derivative. Newton is a purely local method, which can be trapped to any root. You need to start close enough to the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I understand this problem. What I do not understand is, how this technique is modified so that it can be used to speed up training of neural networks. So far I have found some hessian modification techniques, that adjust the direction of the step.